# Calculations in my program are being outputted wrong but the code seems to be right? 

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class date {
public static int t1;           //integers for methods
public static int t2;
public static int x = 0;        //integer for looping
public static int y1;
public static int m1;
public static int d1;
public static int y2;
public static int m2;
public static int d2;

public static void date1() {
    do                                                                      //along with "while" statement. Makes loop if error occurs
{   
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {                                                                   // try (run program as normal)
        System.out.println("Please enter the first date ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the year: ");                      //entering date
        y1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
        m1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the day: ");
        d1 = scanner.nextInt();
        break;                                                              // break loop if input is correct
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {               // response to "Try". if input is incorrect error will be displayed
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.err.println("You must enter intergers. Please try again. ");
    }
     x = x + 1 ;                                                                // set loop to three attempts
}   while (x < 3) ;                                                         //do process occurs while attempts are under < 4

}

public static void caldate1() {
    do                                                                      //along with "while" statement. Makes loop if error occurs
{   
    int j = 693502;
    try {
        if (m1 == 1 || m1 == 3 || m1 == 5 || m1 == 7 || m1 == 8 || m1 == 10  // if/else statements to set proper numbers of days in each month
                || m1 == 12) {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 31);
        } else if (m1 == 2) {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 28);
        } else if (m1 == 4 || m1 == 6 || m1 == 9 || m1 == 11) {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 30);
        }
        if (t1 >= j)                                                        //if/else statement to catch error if date inputted isnt over jan 1st 1900
        { break;}                                                           // break loop if date is greater or equal to jan 1st 1900
        else {
            System.err.printf("Please enter a date after Jan 1st 1900.\n");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {                   //error if date too small
        System.err.println("You must enter intergers. Please try again. ");
    }
     x = x + 1 ;                                                                // set loop to three attempts
    }   while (x < 3) ; 
}

public static void date2() {
    do                                                                      // process to follow if length == 5
{   
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try  {                                                                  // try (run program as normal)
        System.out.println("Please enter the second date ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the year: ");                       // entering second date
        y2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
        m2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the day: ");
        d2 = scanner.nextInt();
          break;                                                                // break loop if input is correct
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {               //   response to "try". if input is incorrect error will be displayed
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.err.println("You must enter intergers. Please try again. ");
    }
     x = x + 1 ;                                                                // set loop to three attempts
}   while (x < 3)  ;                                                            //do process occurs while attempts are under < 4

}

public static void caldate2() {
     do                                                                 //all code is same as in caldate1()... just second set of variables.
{   
    int j = 693502;
    try {
        if (m2 == 1 || m2 == 3 || m2 == 5 || m2 == 7 || m2 == 8 || m2 == 10
                || m2 == 12) {
            t2 = ((365 * y2) + d2 + 31);
        } else if (m2 == 2) {
            t2 = ((365 * y2) + d2 + 28);
        } else if (m2 == 4 || m2 == 6 || m2 == 9 || m2 == 11) {
            t2 = ((365 * y2) + d2 + 30);
        }
        if (t2 >= j) 
        { break;}
        else {
            System.err.printf("Please enter a date after Jan 1st 1900.\n");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
        System.err.println("You must enter intergers. Please try again. ");
    }
     x = x + 1  ;                                                               // set loop to three attempts
    }   while (x < 3) ; 
}
public static void finaldate1() {
    x = Math.abs(t1 - t2);  //calculate total day difference. output absolute value so that result is always positive
    System.out.println("The difference between the two dates is: " + x  + " days.");    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    date1();
    caldate1();
    date2();
    caldate2();
    finaldate1();


}
    }
```

Say for example you enter Feb 28th, 2011 and March 1st, 2011.
The number of days should be 1. Yet it calculates 24. Anyone know what the issue can be? Because when I enter other dates is calculates the dates just fine.

Comment: Why not just use [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Hi Theo, did you use a debugger and step through the program yet? Usually a debugger is really good at figuring out these sort of issues.

Comment: Shouldnt there be some sort of month scaling?  I mean, for February, it would be (year * 365) + 31 (Number of days in Jan) + days.  Why is there a + 28 in Feb?  I think the algorithm that converts y,m,d to t is all wrong.  Also, why is it wrapped in a do-while loop when it should just be executed once?

Comment: I'd recommend generally untangling your code first. Don't use fields as local variables. Don't use `do..while` to perform a loop with a fixed number of iterations. Exchange data between functions as parameters and return values instead of fields. It's not clear what the magic number assigned to `j` means. Whatever it is, it's never changed and should be a constant. The purpose of `calcdate` and `finaldate` isn't clear – what step in the computation do they represent? If `calcdate1` and `calcdate2` perform the same computation they should be one function.

Comment: Also, there's no need to catch InputMismatchException where it won't ever be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. don't do that. Create two GregorianCalendar classes, convert both to milliseconds and subtract to find the difference. Then convert back to days.

Make sure you watch the month because GregorianCalendar is stupidly 0 based.

Comment: While true, using existing APIs is usually not applicable on homework assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting this into your algorithm.  I have an array of ints representing the number of days in each month.  Then if you are looking at, for instance, February (month == 2), then you would add all the values before the 2nd element in the array to your total (t).  I also restructured the method by adding parameters because your design is presently ugly (You have to functions that do the exact same thing, but written twice).

EDIT: Im assuming month is 0 indexed when they input it.  If it isnt, then subtract 1 from it before passing it into this method.

```
public static int months[] = new int {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    //Note Im assuming error checking has already been done on the data (especially month)
public static int caldate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    int t = 0;
    t += year * 365; // assume no leap years

    for(int i = 0; i < month && i < 12; i++)
    {
       t += months[i];
    }

    t += day;

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using joda time. It lets you do simple math on dates without too much hassle, and counts months from 1 to 12.

```
DateMidnight dm1 = new DateMidnight(y1, m1, d1);
DateMidnight dm2 = new DateMidnight(y2, m2, d2);
Days days = Days.daysBetween(dm1, dm2);
int dayCount = days.getDays();
```

Comment: It's already been established that this is a homework assignment, using an existing solution will likely not be accepted.